# Como puedo hacer para que sesion.setAttribute("Apellidos", dbapellidos); me coja dos apellidos

Tags: java, jsp, session

Tengo una clase en la que obtengo dos apellidos de una base de datos;

```
dbapellidos=rs.getString("Apellidos");
```

pero quiero pasarlo a una página jsp mediante session

```
sesion.setAttribute("Apellidos", dbapellidos);
```

y al obtenerlo en la página, solo me sale el primer apellido:

```
session.getAttribute("Apellidos");
```

He probado a poner dos apellidos seguidos por un guión y si me lo coge.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Tiene pinta de que el la base de datos sólo se guarda uno...

Comment: `setAttribute` no te cambiará el valor que le pasas. O bien en el `setAttribute` ya solo pasas un apellido, o después de `getAttribute` haces un `split` o similar.

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes la librería `commons-lang` en el classpath de tu aplicación:

```
sesion.setAttribute("Apellidos", StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(dbapellidos));
```

y

```
String apellidos = session.getAttribute( StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("Apellidos"));
```